# Missing folders after building the project with React Js

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend

After building the project with React Js, the folder called images does not appear. And css doesn't look right (after opening index.html).

This is the folder that comes after npm run build

Comment: React is a JavaScript library for creating user interfaces. It has nothing to do with bundling, preprocessing, compiling etc. Are you using a framework like next or a build system like webpack?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.